# Solr, multiple indexes

Tags: sql, solr, lucene

I want to index 2 different entities (2 tables in SQL in this case) into my Lucene index. One table containing products, another containing news items.

To be able to use the same search method (query) to search for both products and news items, I understand they must be in the same index, so a several core setup of Solr wouldn't work - right?

In data-config.xml I have defined 2 document types with corresponding entities.

In schema.xml I have defined fields for products and news items as well.
In my databse design (tables) my product table's unique key is called "ProductID", where as my news item's unique key is called "Id" (this is made by the CMS I'm using).

In data-config.xml should I just map both my unique id's to the same "name". Would that be all to make this work?

Am I following the right approach here?

Example of what I'm thinking;

data-config.xml

```
<!-- Products --> 
 <document name="products">  
    <entity name="product" dataSource="sqlServer" pk="ProductID" query="SELECT 
        ProductID,
        ProductNumber,
        ProductName,
        FROM EcomProducts">
        <field column="ProductID" name="**Id**"/> 
        <field column="ProductNumber" name="ProductNumber"/> 
        <field column="ProductName" name="ProductName"/> 
    </entity>  
  </document>

<!-- News items ---> 
  <document name="newsitems">  
    <entity name="newsitems" dataSource="sqlServer" pk="id" query="SELECT 
        Id,
        NewsItemTitle,
        NewsItemContent,
        FROM ItemType_NewsItems">
        <field column="Id" name="**Id**"/> 
        <field column="NewsItemTitle" name="NewsItemTitle"/> 
        <field column="NewsItemContent" name="NewsItemContent"/> 
    </entity>  
  </document>
```

schema.xml

```
 <!-- Products --->
 <field name="**Id**" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />  
 <field name="ProductNumber" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" /> 
 <field name="ProductName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>

 <!-- Tips og fif --->      
 <field name="**Id**" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />   
 <field name="NewsItemTitle" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />  
 <field name="NewsItemContent" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

**Id**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search them together, I would map the metadata to a common schema. Perhaps both ProductName and NewItemTitle would go in a "title" field. Some metadata will be unique to each type. Or you can index the info twice, once as ProductName and once as title.

Unless you can be sure the IDs will always, always be unique across the two sources, you may want to prefix them. It is also very handy to have a field that marks the type of each document. That allows searching only one type and, in DIH, you can use it to delete only one type.

In your SQL, you can add columns like this:

```
concat('product-',cast(ProductId as char)) as id,
'product' as type,
```

That is MySQL syntax, it might need tweaking for SQLServer.

Comment: Thanks Walter. In my entities in data-config i mappen both entities id's to the the field "Id", and productName and itemName to the field "Name".

In schema I copied several fields to a text_general filed called "text" and set defaultSearchField to that field.

So my jQuery-objects now consist of fields from both products and items.